# snipMate does not work

Tags: vim, snipmate

I followed the [Pathogen way](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate) to install snipMate and I did include

```
:filetype plugin on
```

in `.vimrc` as the [home page of snipMate plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) suggested.

Now when I type `fr` in a .tex file and press TAB nothing happens as expected.

I also tried [this one](https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim) but even that one did not work.

What am I missing? I am using vim 7.4 from 2013 Aug 10.

Comment: What does `:verbose imap <Tab>` show?

Comment: Then it's not properly installed (though I would have expected `No mapping found`). Check the output of `:scriptnames` for the snipMate files.

Comment: what if verbose says now `<F2>`?

Comment: scriptnames does list snipmate

Comment: Did you type the `<Tab>` as 5 characters? Please do so!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59943/discussion-between-gergely-and-ingo-karkat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I blindly installed Pathogen with curl, but the link on that page was outdated. The proper link is https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tpope/vim-pathogen/master/autoload/pathogen.vim. Also `.vimrc` should start with

```
execute pathogen#infect()
```

This solved the problem and now vim reacts to `<TAB>`.